# Error getting specific API response location which is pushed in an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm storing the API in the global array (tempdata) and when I print tempdata I'll get the response stores in the array but the problem here is when I try to get the specific array location like tempdata[0] or tempdata[1] it gives me undefined.
error if I use console.log(tempdata[0]);

printed array on console:

```
tempdataaa 
[]
0: {values: {…}, series: Array(1), truncated: false}
1: {values: {…}, series: Array(1), truncated: false}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

component code:

```
let tempdata: any =[];
 for (let a = 0; a < this.checkDevice.length; a++) {
  this.httpRequestService.ChartData(this.dateTo, this.checkDevice[a], this.mergeactive[0][a], 
    this.dateFrom).then(mresp => {
            tempdata.push(mresp) ;
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to access object like an array. To do that you should map every object and push it into the array like this:

```
.then(mresp => {
        const mapped = Object.keys(mresp).map(key => mresp[key]);
        //now you can log map element and access it with indexes
 });
```

Comment: But still if I push mapped into a global array (tempdata), I'm not been able to get the indexes of the array.